# Are Christians who question the authenticity of modern day bible(s) or the notion of Trinity considered "Ahlul Kitab"?

Tags: prophet-isa, christianity, bible, ahlul-kitab

I know someone who was raised Christian and continues to believe in God, but questions the modern day bible and believes it to have been altered, he also questions the notion of the Trinity, and whether Jesus was simply a human and not is not to be considered the son of God.
My understand is that what defines "Ahlul Kitab" are that they believe in God and believe and follow the guidance of the bible/torah based on them being Christian or Jewish, but in situations where someone questions the modern day version of the bible and believes it to have been altered, is he still considered "Ahlul Kitab"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If he is considered a follower of Christianity, then he is from Ahlul Kitab. Indeed, every religion has different branches, but  they are still followers of that religion.

[Reference](https://en.wikishia.net/view/People_of_the_Book)

Comment: That's what I am looking to get clarification on--is he considered a Christian or a follower of Christianity based on what I outlined in my initial question.

Comment: @Bog yes he is ahl ul kitab. changes of believes makes him move from one branch to another inside the ahl al kitab.

Comment: But surely there are some basics that need to be upheld. I'm sure at some point, some deviation would lead one to be considered outside of the umbrella. So what are those basics that are required for someone to be considered ahl al kitab?

Comment: @Bog The basics is that someone considers themselves a follower of Jesus Christ.